# How to call Knockout bindingHandler->Update after DOM is updated

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, knockout.js, bindinghandlers

I'm using jquery accordion in a KO bindingHandler, I have to populate the DOM, used by accordion UI, using ajax by an app requirement.

```
this.faqList = ko.observableArray();
$.ajax({
  url: 'getFaqs'
}).done(function( data ) {
  that.faqList(data);
});
```

My bindingHandler should be as simple as

```
ko.bindingHandlers.koAccordion = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).accordion(valueAccessor());

  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      $(element).accordion(valueAccessor());
  }
};
```

The update method is called when the observableArray (faqList) changes, but at that moment UI accordion needs the DOM structure already populated which is not true, seems KO creates after the update method is called.
How could I achieve call update after the DOM structure is populated with the new contents?

Here's the default DOM.

```
<ul class="question-list" data-bind="koAccordion: {
          active: false,
          autoHeight: false, 
          collapsible: true}">
  <!-- ko foreach: faqList -->
    <li>
      <div class="header">
        <span class="rigth-arrow"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: title"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2 data-bind="text: title"></h2>
        <div data-bind="text: content"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
  </ul>
```

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/upwDi)

Comment: I added a demo.  What's the problem?  It seems to work.

Comment: Not really, accordion created the UI classes but the events were not binded.

Answer (score 3):

`koAccordion.update` is useless because you never update that binding value: it's static in the markup and contains no observables. `foreach` binding provides `afterRender` callback for your purposes:

```
var vm = function() {
    // ...
    this.initAccordion = function(element) {
        $(element).accordion(accordionOptions);
    };
};


<!-- ko foreach: { data: faqList, afterRender: initAccordion } -->
```

However, in this case you have to move accordion options out of binding values. If you insist on having custom binding one way to do this is to delegate work to `foreach` binding, inserting `afterRender` into binding values on the way:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.koAccordion = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel,
                   bindingContext) {
        var newValue = ko.computed(function() {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            value.afterRender = function(element) {
                $(element).accordion(value);
            };
            return value;
        });
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, newValue,
            allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel,
                     bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor,
            allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

Using it like this:

```
<ul class="question-list" data-bind="koAccordion: {
      data: faqList,
      active: false,
      autoHeight: false, 
      collapsible: true }">
   <li>...bindings...</li>
</ul>
```

See demo page I forked from the one in the post: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IJpuj

Comment: "If you insist on having custom binding" AfterRender and DOM dependecy in VM is a antipattern so custom binding is much better

Comment: Great, now, I had to add some code in order to bind accordion when that last item added was rendered

Answer (score 1):

```
This is my final code
ko.bindingHandlers.koAccordion = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var newValue = ko.computed(function() {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    value.afterRender = function(renderedElement, loopEntryObject) {
      if ( loopEntryObject == value.data()[value.data().length - 1] ) {
        if ($(element).data('accordion')) {
          $(element).accordion('destroy');
        }
        $(element).accordion(value);
      }
    };
    return value;
  });
  return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
}
```